# Meaning? header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');

Tags: php, mysql, header

I often see this code below in posts. What does it mean and how can this hurt or help someone adding it on the header?

```
ob_start();
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

Comment: RTLM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P

Comment: @MarcB I wondered few days ago, but now I have to ask. What does the `L` stand for? :-) (Sorry for the off-topic comment)

Comment: Sorry to put it this way, but you gave someone (overseas, nonetheless) write permissions to your website and now you're worried what they might have done to your site?

Comment: I gave them access to and ftp but in there it had access to my mysql username, server, and password. I thought I hid it but he echoed out the vars.

Comment: @Havelock In my head it sounds like *read the lucking manual*...

Comment: @Havelock "Lovely", perhaps?

Comment: @Havelock: I used to use the standard RTFM, but some people suggested it was too harsh. so.. "Linked".

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the clarification :-) How could it be too harsh, there's a whole [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtfm) on it?! :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P3P is the Platform for Privacy Prefences Project. It is intended to make compact privacy policy statements.

You can break down this statement based off [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20141127114127/http://www.p3pwriter.com/LRN_111.asp) resource:

- **IDC**: This is an Access descriptor. This grants access to identifiable contact information.
- **DSP**: This is a privacy policy token concerning dispute resolution.
- **COR**: Errors by your service will be remedied by your service.
- **ADM**: Information can be used for technical support, without consent
- **DEVi**: etc. etc. etc. (I'm not going to go through all of these.)

I don't know why any hacker would put that into a header, but be sure you revert the changes.

Comment: The link is dead on 24th Oct 2015.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh Fixed via Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 3):

The **Platform for Privacy Preferences Project**, or P3P, is a protocol allowing websites to declare their intended use of information they collect about browsing users. Designed to give users more control of their personal information when browsing, P3P was developed by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C).

The specification is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/P3P/